# Leiningen: compile only modified java source files

Tags: java, clojure, compilation, leiningen

I'm using leiningen's :java-source-paths and it's compiling the java source every time. is there a way for lein to tell if it hasn't changed?

Here's an example project to illustrate the problem: https://github.com/yayitswei/leinwithjava

Comment: Which lein version are you using? Recent versions should check timestamps of the source files against the compiled class files.

Comment: I'm using the latest, `Leiningen 2.3.2 on Java 1.6.0_51 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`

Comment: Then it sounds like there's something funky going on with your build environment. [Here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/src/leiningen/javac.clj#L12) is the code in `javac` that selects only those source files that have changed.

Comment: Still having this problem, so I created a simple example to illustrate  it- just started a blank lein project and added a java source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have Clojure and Java source code mixed together in the same source tree, and are then pointing `:java-source-paths` at a sub-directory of the root of that source tree. A more typical approach for polyglot projects is to manage separate directories for source code in each language.

The reason you're seeing Java source recompiled every time you invoke `lein` is that the check to detect stale Java sources only works if `:java-source-paths` points at the root of the Java package tree. Note that the [`stale-java-sources` function](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/src/leiningen/javac.clj#L12) in the javac task takes the path of each source file relative to the `:java-source-paths` directory, and uses that to construct the path for the corresponding class file relative to the `:compile-path` directory. In your case, Leiningen was expecting to find `target/classes/TestClass.class` when the actual compiled class file was `target/classes/main/java/TestClass.class`.

I was able to fix your sample project by switching it over to the following directory structure:

```
$ find src
src
src/java
src/java/main
src/java/main/java
src/java/main/java/TestClass.java
src/clj
src/clj/leinwithjava
src/clj/leinwithjava/core.clj
```

And in `project.clj`:

```
:source-paths ["src/clj"]
:java-source-paths ["src/java"]
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I think the behavior of leiningen is incorrect in considering more than just Java files when deciding to recompile. You got my upvote. ;-)

Comment: You got my bounty. Though I ran into a second more minor problem when I set up my actual project this way- when I run `lein run`, I get an error saying it couldn't find the java class. I have to run `lein jar` first in order to compile the java classes. Unfortunately it doesn't duplicate with the sample project. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Bill the problem wasn't lein considering non-Java source files, it was that it couldn't match Java files to their compiled class files due to a java-source-paths that didn't point to the root of the package tree.

Comment: @yayitswei if you have :prep-tasks defined in your project.clj, make sure it includes javac (the default prep-tasks includes javac and compile, but if you override it then you have to be sure to include those).

Comment: I didn't override `:prep-tasks` in my `project.clj`.

Comment: @yayitswei Then I'm out of ideas. I'd suggest either taking it to the Leiningen mailing list (they're very responsive), or creating a reproducible sample project that illustrates the problem and posting it as a new question.